# Row count off by one in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete empty rows.  Row 885 is a non-empty row and should be retained.  However, my code says (and shows in the msgbox) that 885 is empty and should be deleted.  When it gets to i=884, it prints what is really in row 885 and says it will NOT be deleted.  So, I'm confused.  It appears to be acting upon the data properly, yet it's reporting the row number wrong.  I suspect you're going to tell me offsets are zero based and rows start at 1, so if lastrow=888 (1 based), then I need to subtract 1 to match the offset.  so what I see as row 885 in the spreadsheet is really row 884 as an offset.

But... when i=row 885 has data, the offset is 884.  And when i=884, the offset is 883... so why is it printing what's in row 885???  Seriously confused here.  What am I getting wrong?

Last but most importantly... it's deleting the wrong row!  How can it be referencing the right data, yet still deleting the wrong row???

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
var i = range.getLastRow();
var msg;
var colNum;

for (; i > 1; i--) {  // I like to start at the end
  var foundAvalue=0;  // reset flag for each row

  rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1); 

  var valArray=rowRange.getValues();
  var foundAvalue=0;
  var msg;
  var totalColumns=rowRange.getNumColumns();

   colNum=0;   

   while (colNum < totalColumns && (foundAvalue==0)) {
     if (valArray[0][colNum] != '') {       
       foundAvalue=1; 
       msg="Row " + i + " =" + valArray[0];
       Browser.msgBox(msg);
       msg="Row " + i + " will not be deleted";
       Browser.msgBox(msg);
     }
     colNum++;
   }
   if (foundAvalue == 0) {
      msg="Row " + i + " =" + valArray[0] + "WILL be deleted";
      Browser.msgBox(msg);
           // delete empty row
      // s.deleteRow(i);
   }

 } // end for(i)
```

Comment: For anyone that comes along in the future... RocketDonkey helped me understand that the basic problem with the above code is that the offset() function needs "i-1", where I was using just "i".

Comment: The reason is that offset() returns it's answer as a zero based value.  So my range which would normally be 1 to LastRow is returned by offset as 0 to LastRow-1.  One has to be careful because functions like deleteRow() expect a row from 1 to LastRow, not zero based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is some code which should accomplish what you want. You are correct in that the root of the problem is in the 0-based indexing. The tricky part is that JavaScript/Apps Script arrays use 0-based indexing, but when you call something like `getLastRow()`, the returned range is 1-based. All-in-all, your code is good - it is only that issue that is tripping you up. Hope this helps:

```js
function DeleteFun(){
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = mySheet.getDataRange();

  // Iterate using a counter, starting at the last row and stopping at
  // the header (assumes the header is in the first row)
  for (i = mySheet.getLastRow() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var foundAvalue = 0;
    // Here we get the values for the current row and store in an array
    rowRange = range.getValues()[i]
    // Now we iterate through that array
    for (j = 0; j <= rowRange.length; j++) {
      // If any non-nulls are found, alert they won't be deleted and move on
      if (rowRange[j] != null && rowRange[j] != '') {
        foundAvalue = 1; 
        msg="Row " + (i+1) + " =" + rowRange[0] + " and will not be deleted";
        Browser.msgBox(msg);
        break;
       }
    }

    if (foundAvalue == 0) {
      msg="Row " + (i+1) + " =" + rowRange[0] + "WILL be deleted";
      Browser.msgBox(msg);
      // Delete empty row
      mySheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, so it looks like you're starting the row counter "i" from lastRow - 1, which implies i is being used as an index for an array.  So "getvalues" is apparently returning a zero-based range.  Hmmm.  I'm still not seeing it.  You're taking a row of data, and stuffing it into an array.  So what used to be "rowNum" is now addressed through the array as "rowNum - 1" to accommodate the zero based indexing.  So if my data goes from row 1 to row 888, the array index is 0 to 887.  I get that, and always have.  Now since you made no change to deleteRow - which was only commented (cont.)

Comment: The `getLastRow` piece returns the actual row number (starting at 1), so we subtract 1 to allow the `getValues[i]` function to properly reference the 0-based array that it returns. Does that make sense? Happy to help until it is clear :)

Comment: so I wouldn't lose data...  I'm guessing that deleteRow also needs zero based indexing??  OK, the primary difference between what you and I did seems to be that I used the "offset" function to get the range using the rowNum, and you eliminated that step.  You got the range using rowNum-1.  So you're getting row 887 instead of 888.  I don't understand why that would work any better.  Now we simply skip the last row and include the first - header - row which I don't need to process.  I still don't understand why my code deletes the wrong row.  Did you test your code?

Comment: Yes I understand what getLastRow does... and I understand that arrays are zero based.  But as I mentioned while you were typing... it appears your code is getting LastRow-1 and skipping lastRow which might or might not have data in it.  I'm obviously still missing something.  I suspect that offset() function I was using may be the key?

Comment: @AB Away from the computer now but will give a more detailed answer when I can. Not using offset avoids an additional function call, but is essentially the same. As for the header row, my bad - my data didn't have one. To adjust, modify the main loop so that the final condition is `i > 0` (this will stop when it hits the header, assuming it is in the first row). I'll retest with those adjustments, but it worked previously. Also, I would suggest using `Logger.log()` as a way to test - you can run the function and press `Control+Enter` in the Script Editor to view the output.

Comment: @AB Just tested it, and it does work if you make the adjustmnets. You are correct in your assumption that when you delete you need to increase the row number by 1. The reason is that as we discussed, when you delete a row, you are giving it the actual row number to delete (starting at 1), so if we are iterating using a 0-based approach (as we are), we need to increase the row counter (`i`) by one in order to get things to mesh. I'll update my answer with the proper delete code.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help.  The question is, why is MY code deleting the wrong row?  The key may be in my statement wherein I stated "But... when i=row 885 has data, the offset is 884. And when i=884, the offset is 883... so why is it printing what's in row 885???" To re-word that statement a bit...  rowNum (or i) is 884 so the offset or index is 883.  Yet it's printing what's in row 885!!!  So it's off not by one, but by two!!  Take my code and demonstrate to yourself what it does.  If you agree that offset() should provide the same results, then why is my code wrong??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19724/discussion-between-a-b-and-rocketdonkey)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in 'pure' array as well if you don't use formulas in your sheet.

Like this for example :

```
function deleteEmptyRows(){ 
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
 var targetData = new Array();
 for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
 if(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,'')!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};// checks the whole row
 Logger.log(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,''))
 }
 sh.getDataRange().clear(); // clear the whole sheet
 sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);//write back all non empty rows
 }
```

Comment: Well, thanks for providing an alternative way to get the job done.  Gives me something new to learn... join, replace, push... I'm sure someday I'll look into all this...

Comment: arrays are like chocolates : once you taste it you can't resist anymore ;-) give it a try and you'll get infected !!

Comment: I'm very familiar with arrays.  It's the other unknowns that are going to take time for my brain to not just process, but research.  I was boiling water over a campfire.  You've just cooked eggplant parmigiana in a microwave and are telling me to do the same.  It'll be awhile.  But thanks for letting me know what's out there!